# Transclusion property in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am learning angularjs.I got stucked in the tranclusion property as it confused me.How ng-transclude works? Will it replace the content inside the dom marked with ng-transclude with transcluded element(the element to be transcluded) or simply append the transcluded element to the dom marked with ng-transclude?

I referred egghead angularjs video tutorial for transclusion property
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-transclusion-basics

There It was mentioned that ng-transclude simply appends the transcluded element to the dom marked with ng-transclude.But when I tried this,it is not so

Here is my html file

learning.hmtl

```
<html ng-app="learnangular">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="learnscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="firstcontroller">
<custom-directive><div>This is transcluded part</div></custom-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my script file
learnscript.js

```
var app=angular.module("learnangular",[]);

app.controller("firstcontroller",function($scope){
$scope.dirobject="directive object";
});

app.directive("customDirective",function(){

    return {

   restrict:"E",
   transclude:true,
   replace:false,
   template:"<input type='text' ng-model='dirobject'></input>"+
   "<div ng-transclude>{{dirobject}}</div>",

   link:function(scope,element,attr){
   }
    };
});
```

ng-transclude replaces the content inside the dom marked with ng-transclude.why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

I have understood now.The video was recorded with angular js version 1.0.x and the version I am using is the latest one. Actually,the transcluded markup completely replaces the contents of the element with the ng-transclude attribute in latest versions. In previous versions, the transcluded markup would be appended.Thanks everyone